# Validate if input is url or email in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, validation

I am trying to validate a field but I am not able to do it.
I have this Request Validator

```
public function rules()
    {
        return  [            
            ...
            'input' => 'required|url|email',
        ];
    }
```

What I want to do is to validate if the input is **url** or **email**, can be one of them, what can I do? Here I am validating both cases, but the input can be one of them. Thanks.

Comment: I'd make a custom validation rule (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) that creates a pair of validators (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) and runs it through both. If it passes one or the other, pass the custom rule.

Comment: For reference, this is what the `url` and `email` rules check to determine validity: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1997 and https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L728.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'input' => ['required', function ($field, $value) {
            $data = [$field => $value];
            $emailValidator = Validator::make($data, [$field => 'email']);
            $urlValidator = Validator::make($data, [$field => 'url']);

            if ($urlValidator->passes() || $emailValidator->passes()) {
                return true;
            }

            $this->validator->getMessageBag()->add($field, $field . ' must be a valid email address or a valid url');

            return false;
        }],
    ];
}
```